# Hearthstone Deck Comparison

Tags: hearthstone

Say you have your deck and there is a new, but still rather similar, deck. Is there any way to **quickly compare** the two decks in order to see the changes?

*At the moment I'm just checking the cards one by one.*

Comment: since it's text based, could always use something like winmerge

Comment: @Aequitas Yes that's not bad. I"ve also thought about it before. I was wondering though if there is a better method.

Answer (score 5):

If you have both decks in a text file, say DeckA.txt and DeckB.txt as simple plaintext, you could simply use any **diff** tool to compare them.

On Linux, typing in a terminal:

```
diff -q DeckA.txt DeckB.txt > Changes.txt
```

will produce the changes between the two files, stored in the file `Changes.txt`. You can control the output to a significant degree, see also the manual page, which you can access via `man diff`. On Windows, you can use a [minGW](http://www.mingw.org/) terminal shell to get access to GNU diff or one of the many GUI tools like [TortoiseIDiff](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html) or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en).

Modern windows versions have PowerShell, which also knows the `diff` command, although here it appears not to consider the order of the individual lines within the file. This may be what you want, but a simple `sort` before `diff` would do the same for the GNU version;

```
sort DeckA.txt > DeckA_s.txt
sort DeckB.txt > DeckB_s.txt
diff -q DeckA_s.txt DeckB_s.txt > Changes.txt
rm DeckA_s.txt
rm DeckB_s.txt
```

Comment: Also to add to this, the popular Notepad++ has a built in plugin manager which allows enabling of a compare function which will also display diff

Answer (score 1):

aphid's answer is probably your best bet right now BUT hearthpwn.com is somehow getting close to a feature like this (which would indeed be useful).

Right now you can download the innkeeper app and create an account in order to save your decks to Hearthpwn (you can save them privately if you like).

Then for each deck you get a similar decks tab on the bottom where your deck is compared to all other decks in the website and it shows you a similarity percentage.

This means that Hearthpwn is actually doing what you want to do "behind the scenes".

It has also been suggested as a possible feature here: http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/off-topic/site-feedback-support/51094-possible-to-compare-two-decks

**HOWEVER I'M FEELING CREATIVE**

I wrote some Javascript code (which could easily become a chrome plugin) to help you achieve what you want relatively easily.

**Instructions**

1. Open Chrome and navigate to a hearthpwn.com deck page (for example: http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/735789-from-16-to-legend-malygos-rogue-eu-server)
2. Hit F12 (Chrome Developer Tools pane will appear either on the bottom or on the side of your browser)
3. Click on the Console Tab of the Developer Tools pane.
4. Copy & Paste the javascript code from [this link](https://jpst.it/Uvij) and hit enter ([HERE'S AN IMAGE TO HELP YOU WITH STEPS 3-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHv4f.png))
5. You should get an alert that the html was copied successfully.
6. Visit http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm and paste the HTML you got into the option 3 box.
7. At the bottom of the page Select and Copy the result data (you should see the cards there followed by 2 numbers e.g. Preparation × 2,0 - The first is the number of copies included and the second is the mana cost - so here we have 2 copies of Preparation which costs 0 mana.)
8. Visit https://text-compare.com/ and paste the result data into the left box.
9. Repeat 1-7 for another deck from hearthpwn that you want to compare with the first one.
10. Go Back to https://text-compare.com/ and paste the second result data into the right box and compare them.
11. I think the comparison results will be self-explanatory based on what I told you about the results on step 7. [Here is what I got from comparing the Miracle Rogue Deck I gave you above with a similar Rogue deck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSKvZ.png). As you can see, the other deck (on the left) has one less Swashburglar and no Beneath the Grounds, replacing them with 1x Shadow Strike and 1x Bloodmage Thalnos.

**Bottomline**

You can use Innkeeper to save your decks to Hearthpwn and then you can use my method to compare any of them to any other deck from hearthpwn.

*Disclaimer*

I have tested the code and the whole comparison process and it works perfectly.
If it doesn't work for you feel free to comment and ask me anything, because it means you're doing something wrong and I have failed with my instructions hehe.

Answer (score 0):

[HearthstoneTopDecks](http://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com) has that function. You have to load the decks first but if you want to compare with pros or streamer decks those are usually already loaded. The tool looks really good, [here for example](http://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com/deck-comparison/?deck_ids%5B%5D=40652&deck_ids%5B%5D=40299).